# Set the "include hidden / filtered data" option for a spreadsheet chart via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Writing data into a google spreadsheet and creating a chart is done using google apps script. As I plot multiple charts onto the same sheet, I set 1 row to the height of the chart, hide all rows with data for that chart, repeat this for every chart and therefore have all the data belonging to each chart hidden "behind" it.

All works great except that a chart is not showing hidden data by default. Opening the google spreadsheet and editing the chart, a checkbox becomes visible to "Include hidden / filtered data". By checking it, the chart shows data as I want to. I would want to set this option via google apps script as well and expect to have an option similar to
`.setOption('includeHidden', true)`

Some code to illustrate my current work:

```
var headerRow = ['h-Axis', 'data A', 'datalabel A', 'data B', 'datalabel B', 'data C']
var chart = mySheet.newChart().asComboChart()
.addRange(mySheet.getRange(rangeStartAfterHeaderRow, startColumn, numOfRowsExcludingHeader, numOfColumns))
.setTitle('My Chart')
.setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.TOP)
.setPosition(startRow, startColumn, 0, 0)
.setOption('isStacked', true)
.setOption('width', 800)
.setOption('height', 500)

// axis and data label columns are automatically interpreted as such; series index correspond as: 0=ColB, 1=ColD, 2=ColF
.setOption('series', 
           {0:{type:'bars', color:'#80ba27', labelInLegend:headerRow[1], targetAxisIndex:0},
            1:{type:'bars', color:'#CC3816', labelInLegend:headerRow[3]},
            2:{type:'steppedArea', color:'#4F80FF', labelInLegend:headerRow[5]}
           })

.setOption('vAxes', 
           {0:{title:'Vertical axis label'}})        

;

mySheet.insertChart(chart.build());
```

Thank you,
Joram

Comment: And? What does documentation say? Is this something that can be done in the Google visualization API? If not, I wouldn't expect it to be possible in Apps Script either (apps script implementation often has fewer features than the official Google implemention for 3rd parties).

Comment: This certainly cannot be done in visualization as there is no "hidden" data in DataTables (as far as I know). Thx for further replies.